# What Would Happen When NAT Mapping is Dropped

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, router, nat

As far as I Know, NAT will set a timeout value for every tcp or udp mapping entry, suppose here is a NAT and it has two mapping entries: one as udp pair, and the other as tcp pair. My questions are:

When the tcp/udp pair mapping is dropped because of timeout, what would happen to the endpoints? Will the endpoints get notified by NAT? What would happen if the endpoints still try to send packets to their communication peers?

Answer (score -1):

TCP connections have a 'keep communication alive' mechanism, which will keep the mapping alive too. So you are unlikely to face a timeout. But, let's imagine you reach a timeout (with UDP or not), your code will throw an error, at most when you try to write a packet. This is handled by the TCP layer.

Comment: when NAT decides to drop a mapping, will it send any packets to the endpoints?

Comment: On top of my head, it is not a requirement in the protocol, so I would say no, it won't send a warning packet. In fact, it would be impossible with UDP, because there is more than 1 possible destination.